# Redirect sub-folders to a new folder in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have been struggling to redirect old urls to the new website pages.

Goal is to redirect many sub-sub folder pages like :
**https://www.example.com/news/events/event18**

to a unique folder : **https://www.example.com/focus**

Using htaccess file in Wordpress, i tried :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder1/oldpage1/(.*) /newfolder/$1
```

Result is:

```
https://www.example.com/newfolder/oldpage1
```

Another method:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/newfolder [R=301,L]
```

Result is the same !

I have ton of old urls and I want to avoid the manual **Redirect 301** for all ot them.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is everything going to come out of */news*?  Or is it going to come out of an additional folder as well?  Example below would check first tier subfolder for one of two names (*news* or *articles*) before doing rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /focus/$1 [L]

# then check if request is in a different folder like /articles/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/articles%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/articles%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/$1 [L]

# otherwise, blindly rewrite to /news (or do nothing by removing this rule to allow a 404 not found)
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/news/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Like that solution ! Thank you